# How to generate custom training data for Stanford relation extraction

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have trained a custom classifier to understand named entities in finance domain. I want to generate custom training data like shown in below link 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/ER/conll04.corp

I can mark the custom relation by hand but want to generate the data format like conll first with my custom named entities.

I have also tried the parser in the following way but that does not generate the relation training data like  Roth and Yih's data mentioned in link https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.html#training.

java -mx150m -cp "stanford-parser-full-2013-06-20/*:" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "penn" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz stanford-parser-full-2013-06-20/data/testsent.txt >testsent.tree

java -mx150m -cp "stanford-parser-full-2013-06-20/*:" edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure -treeFile testsent.tree -conllx

Following is the output of custom ner run separate with the following python code

```
'java -mx2g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.NERClassifierCombiner '\
                '-ner.model classifiers\custom-model.ser.gz '\
                'classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,'\
                'classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,'\
                'classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ' \
                '-textFile '+ outtxt_sent +  ' -outputFormat inlineXML  > ' + outtxt + '.ner'

output:

<PERSON>Charles Sinclair</PERSON> <DESG>Chairman</DESG> <ORGANIZATION>-LRB- age 68 -RRB- Charles was appointed a</ORGANIZATION> <DESG>non-executive director</DESG> <ORGANIZATION>in</ORGANIZATION>
```

So the NER is working standalone fine even i have java code to test it out.

Here is the detailed code for relation data generation

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions");
        props.setProperty("ner.model", "classifiers/custom-model.ser.gz,classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
        // set up Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        // build annotation for a review
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation("Charles Sinclair Chairman -LRB- age 68 -RRB- Charles was appointed a non-executive director");
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        int sentNum = 0;

.............. Rest of the code is same as yours

output:
0   PERSON  0   O   NNP/NNP Charles/Sinclair    O   O   O
0   PERSON  1   O   NNP Chairman    O   O   O
0   PERSON  2   O   -LRB-/NN/CD/-RRB-/NNP/VBD/VBN/DT    -LRB-/age/68/-RRB-/Charles/was/appointed/a  O   O   O
0   PERSON  3   O   JJ/NN   non-executive/director  O   O   O

O   3   member_of_board //I will modify the relation once the data generated with proper NER

The Ner tagging is ok now.  
 props.setProperty("ner.model", "classifiers/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,");
```

Custom NER problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link shows an example of the data: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/ER/conll04.corp

I don't think there is a way to produce this in Stanford CoreNLP.

After you tag the data, you need to loop through the sentences and print out the tokens in that same format, including the part-of-speech tag and the ner tag.  It appears most of the columns have a "O" in them.

For each sentence that has a relationship you need to print out the a line after the sentence in the relation format.  For instance this line indicates the previous sentence has the Live_In relationship:

```
7    0    Live_In
```

Here is some example code to generate the output for a sentence.  You will need to set the pipeline to use your `ner` model instead by setting the `ner.model` property to the path of your custom model.  WARNING: There may be some bugs in this code, but it should show how to access the data you need from the StanfordCoreNLP data structures.

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CreateRelationData {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitymentions");
    // set up Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // build annotation for a review
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("Joe Smith lives in Hawaii.");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    int sentNum = 0;
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      int tokenNum = 1;
      int elementNum = 0;
      int entityNum = 0;
      CoreMap currEntityMention = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class).get(entityNum);
      String currEntityMentionWords = currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).stream().map(token -> token.word()).
          collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
      String currEntityMentionTags =
          currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).stream().map(token -> token.tag()).
              collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
      String currEntityMentionNER = currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.EntityTypeAnnotation.class);
      while (tokenNum <= sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).size()) {
        if (currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).get(0).index() == tokenNum) {
          String entityText = currEntityMention.toString();
          System.out.println(sentNum+"\t"+currEntityMentionNER+"\t"+elementNum+"\t"+"O\t"+currEntityMentionTags+"\t"+
              currEntityMentionWords+"\t"+"O\tO\tO");
          // update tokenNum
          tokenNum += (currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).size());
          // update entity if there are remaining entities
          entityNum++;
          if (entityNum < sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class).size()) {
            currEntityMention = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.MentionsAnnotation.class).get(entityNum);
            currEntityMentionWords = currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).stream().map(token -> token.word()).
                collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
            currEntityMentionTags =
                currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).stream().map(token -> token.tag()).
                    collect(Collectors.joining("/"));
            currEntityMentionNER = currEntityMention.get(CoreAnnotations.EntityTypeAnnotation.class);
          }
        } else {
          CoreLabel token = sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class).get(tokenNum-1);
          System.out.println(sentNum+"\t"+token.ner()+"\t"+elementNum+"\tO\t"+token.tag()+"\t"+token.word()+"\t"+"O\tO\tO");
          tokenNum += 1;
        }
        elementNum += 1;
      }
      sentNum++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("O\t3\tLive_In");
  }
}
```

Comment: StanfordNLPHelp Thanks for the code you sent. Its not generating the custom entity which i have trained.
i am loading my custom classifier like below
      props.setProperty("ner.model", "classifiers/custom-model.ser.gz,classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,classifiers/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");

I have tested the custom classifier separate and it works and understand DEGREE (ex. MBA ) but not working here.

Goal is to use this training data to train a custom relationship classifier could u please help.

Comment: Is the ner working?  Does it create an entity mention for the degree?  Please add an example that is not working to your original question and provide as much detail as you can including what code you are using.

Comment: I have edited my original question. Also i have one more question i want to tag Finance Director only when they appear together but not when Finance appears alone.

Example
<DESIGNATION>Finance Director</DESIGNATION>
But
<O>Finance</O>
Should i ask a different question?

Comment: Also, if you are using a statistical model, you cannot specify how it tags data.  If you want set rules, you might want to use something like RegexNER.  More info here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html

Comment: There was a bug in my code where I didn't update the currEntityMentionNER.  I fixed that in the answer above.  That should fix the issue with everything being a PERSON.

Comment: I'm not sure why "-LRB-/age/68/-RRB-/Charles/was/appointed/a" is being treated as an entity mention.  If you show me the NER tags you are getting for your example sentence that would help me better understand what's going on.

Comment: There may be some bugs in that code above, but it should show how to access all of the necessary Stanford CoreNLP data structures.

Comment: The code does not work, edited the original question.

Comment: I am unclear as to why you are building an EntityMention in your code.  If you run the entitymentions annotator it will create the entity mentions for you.

Comment: Sorry i asked question related to custom relation classifier here. which i am tracking in separate thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932872/relationmention-does-not-understand-custom-ner-tags-and-no-relation-generated

Relation data generation with custom NER model is working fine now, i am also able to integrate regexner on top of custom NER model. 
Thanks for the help this was the easier part of the whole problem i guess..